# How to call Amazon Deequ hasDataType from java

Tags: java, scala, amazon-deequ

I am trying to implement Amazon Deequ functionality from Java.

I am trying to add datatype constains but not able to pass 3rd parameter (assertion) from java

```
 com.amazon.deequ.constraints.Constraint constrains = Constraint.dataTypeConstraint("test", ConstrainableDataTypes.Numeric(), ?,x);
```

Method declation in scala is as below

```
 * @param column Column to compute the data type distribution for.
    * @param dataType The data type that should be checked in the assertion.
    * @param assertion Function from the ratio of the data type in the specified column to boolean.
    * @param hint A hint to provide additional context why a constraint could have failed
    * @return
    */
  def dataTypeConstraint(
      column: String,
      dataType: ConstrainableDataTypes.Value,
      assertion: Double => Boolean,
      hint: Option[String] = None)
    : Constraint = {
```

Answer (score 0):

From Java you should be able to call `dataTypeConstraint` by implementing `AbstractFunction1` and passing it as an argument:

```java
scala.Function1<Double, Boolean> function = new scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1<Double, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(Double value) {
        // implement the actual assertion here
        return value >= 0;
    }
};

Constraint.dataTypeConstraint("column", dataType, function, scala.Option.apply("a hint"));
```

Comment: When i pass the function then I am getting below error

Required type: Function1<Object,Object>
Provided:Function1<Double,Boolean>

Comment: scala.Function1<Object, Object> function = new scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1<Object, Object>() {
            public Object apply(Object value) {
                // implement the actual assertion here
                return (Double)value >= myval;
            }
        };